# org.teiid.adminapi.AdminFactory missing in teiid 8.13.4?

Tags: wildfly, teiid

I am migrating an existing app from teiid-8.8.1c1/jboss-as-7.2.0 to WildFly 9.0.2
Teiid 8.13.4.  I have been able to update dependencies in all cases except one:

I have one class getting an Admin instance from org.teiid.adminapi.AdminFactory as follows:

AdminFactory.getInstance().createAdmin(...)

So that is can get and check status on a VDB.

But is seems that the AdminFactory is no longer part the teidd adminapi.  Is there some new way to get an admin instance?

Answer (score 0):

Per teiid message board, it was moved to teiid-jboss-admin jar:

[TEIID-3503] Development with Embedded teiid should not require dependency on EAP - JBoss Issue Tracker separated out the EAP dependent Admin functionality into the teiid-jboss-admin jar.  It doesn't look like that was called out in the release notes or a specific migration doc, so I'll make sure that gets updated.